# SQL query is really slow when I remove one extra condition

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, sql-tuning

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT top 100 Id
FROM TestTable
where 
    (Code like 'a000' + '%' or contains(Desc , 'a000*' )  )
    AND  (Active!='N' or Active is null)         
    AND  substring(Code,1,1) in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
    ORDER BY Code
```

[image]

It takes almost **70 ms** to run but I have set the active to 'N' when the first character of code is not numeric, so the last where clause is unnecessary but after removing that the following query takes **6 seconds** to run!

```
SELECT top 100 Id
FROM TestTable
where 
    (Code like 'a000' + '%' or contains(Desc , 'a000*' )  )
    AND  (Active!='N' or Active is null)         
    ORDER BY Code
```

I also run this query with database engine tuning advisor but it doesn't have any recomandation. 
[image]

Comment: I could see both queries are same..am i missing some thing

Comment: Try adding execution plans as xml for two queries(slow and fast) as xml

Comment: Questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: Look at the plan (click the "show estimated plan" button in SQL Server Management Studio). Once for each query (each in a separate window). Compare the plans. It should be pretty obvious what the difference is.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2016 19:14:09   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: It shows Index Scan (NonClustered) Cost: 86% in slow query but in fast one it is 12%

Comment: Have you tried flipping around the order of the where clauses?  It may seem silly, but it's possible that the order of execution is coming into play here, especially if there's a large number of records.

Comment: Wild guess `substring(Code,1,1) in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')` causes full scan (nonSARGable condition) + **parallel execution**, while second query is single threaded. Please post actual execution plan for both.

Comment: I have added the execution plan

Comment: @lad2025 I have posted the execution plan, Have you had a chance to take look? Thank you

Comment: @rezord Ok, I see that `SORT` is expensive. Could you remove `ORDER BY` from both queries and compare performance of both?

Comment: @lad2025 I did, the same story!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,serious database design issue if you have to query by substring of a field.
However, if the total number of records which meet the first criteria is not too large, you could use a temporary table:

SELECT ID,code into #Testemp
FROM TestTable
where 
    (Code like 'a000' + '%' or contains(Desc , 'a000*' )  )
    AND  (Active!='N' or Active is null)
    ORDER BY Code
--Then:

SELECT top 100 ID from #testemp where substring(Code,1,1) in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
order by Code

Comment: Both generate the same size result and I want to remove the extra unnecessary condition from my where clause

Comment: I think that's kinda what he was trying to say, he shouldn't HAVE to query by a substring of a field.  It's not in fact a db design flaw.

Comment: But with substring, it is faster and this is the strange thing!